# Given a large dataset in file A, how can I reference it in a simulation in file B?

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, bigdata, simulation

I am given a file called file.dat that contains simulation data for a robot.  It is 100k+ lines of discrete commands given at 30Hz, three parameters wide:

```
# Time [s]    forward velocity [m/s]    angular velocity[rad/s] 
1248297556.158    0.000      0.000  
1248297556.169    0.000      0.000  
1248297556.180    0.000      0.000  
1248297556.190    0.075      0.240  
1248297556.211    0.075      0.240
```

My question is how to use this data in a python simulator that accepts the same four parameters as inputs.  Should I reference an external file?  Ideally, I'm hoping to work with something along the lines of:

```
for i in file.dat:
    runFunction(i[0],i[1],i[2],i[3])
```

Any thoughts on how I could accomplish this?

EDIT: Included simulation data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description of the layout of the simulation data is rather vague. Can you *please* post a few lines of file.dat?

I'm *guessing* from the code you posted that each line of file.dat consists of 4 bytes of parameter data (followed by a newline).

You need to open a file before you can read from it. Eg,

```
with open("file.dat", "r") as data:
    for line in data:
        runFunction(line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3])
```

or even

```
with open("file.dat", "r") as data:
    for line in data:
        runFunction(*line[:4])
```

---

Here's one way to do it a line at a time:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

''' From
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26153937/given-a-large-dataset-in-file-a-how-can-i-reference-it-in-a-simulation-in-file/26161074#26161074
'''

input_name = "file.dat"

# Lines in file.dat have this format:
# Time [s]    forward velocity [m/s]    angular velocity[rad/s]
# Eg
#1248297556.211    0.075      0.240


def runFunction(timestamp, fwd_vel, ang_vel):
    print "Time %f, Forward velocity %f, Angular velocity %f" % (timestamp, fwd_vel, ang_vel)


def main():
    with open(input_name, "r") as data:
        for line in data:
            #Split line on whitespace into a list of strings
            params = line.split()

            #Convert parameters from strings to floats
            params = [float(s) for s in params]

            #Pass the parameter list 
            runFunction(*params)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you - that's what I was looking for!  This data is delimited in an odd way, however (some spaces, some tabs).  Is there a lightweight way to break this into a nx3 matrix?  My current protocol involves scanning each character with isspace() and returning an element when true.

Comment: Ah. So the parameters aren't just bytes. :) No problem. Python provides various string methods to easily split up strings in various ways. When you say "a nx3 matrix" does that mean you want to read the whole 100k+ line file into one giant matrix? Do you **really** need to do that, or can your program run just getting one line's worth of data at a time? Either way is easy; the "line at a time" method will use less memory, the "whole thing into one giant matrix" method may be a little faster.